# How to merge lists into a list of tuples in Elixir?

Tags: list, tuples, elixir

What is the Elixir approach to merge two lists into a single list of tuples?

```rb
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

# List of tuples from 'list1' and 'list2':
    
result = [{1,5}, {2,6}, {3,7}, {4,8}]
```

Each member of `result` is a tuple, whose first member is from `list1` and the second is from `list2`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with [`Enum.zip/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip/1):

> Zips corresponding elements from a finite collection of enumerables into one list of tuples.

```rb
Enum.zip([[1, 2, 3], [:a, :b, :c], ["foo", "bar", "baz"]])
# [{1, :a, "foo"}, {2, :b, "bar"}, {3, :c, "baz"}]

Enum.zip([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [:a, :b, :c]])
# [{1, :a}, {2, :b}, {3, :c}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using [`List.zip/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#zip/1):

> **[`zip(list_of_lists)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#zip/1)**
>
> **Specs**
>
> `zip([list()]) :: [tuple()]`
>
> Zips corresponding elements from each list in `list_of_lists`.
>
> The zipping finishes as soon as any list terminates.

**Example:**

```rb
    iex(1)> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    iex(2)> list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
    [5, 6, 7, 8]
    iex(3)> result = List.zip([list1, list2])
    [{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}, {4, 8}]
```